# Intuition behind expected values such as $E[X + 1]$

Tags: probability

Suppose we are dealing with a discrete probability distribution and we are looking to find the value of $E[X]$.

$E[X] = \sum_x xP(X = x)$

I read that as take the value of each $x$ multiplied the probability of getting that value  $x$, then sum all the values. And this gives us the mean, ie. the expected value of the random variable $X$.

Now, suppose we have, for example, $E[X + 1]$.

$E[X + 1] = \sum_x (x+1)P(X = x)$

What is this supposed to signify? What way should I intuitively think of it?

Comment: Well the expected mean of $X$ plus $1$, (In this trivial case, use linearity to see that $E(X+1) = E(X) + E(1) = E(X) + 1$) To provide an example: You shall win one coin more than the number of heads you toss. The expected number of heads is $E(X)$ and the expected number of coins gained is $E(X+1) = E(X) + 1$.

Comment: If $X=x$, you are given $x+1$ dollars. What is the "average" amount of money you get?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't really follow what you are saying here?

Comment: You seemed to ask for an explanation of the *meaning* of $E(X+1)$. For example, let $X$ be the result of tossing a fair die. Then $X+1$ is $1$ more than the result, so $2$ to $7$. If you get $1$ more dollar than the number showing on the die, then $E(X+1)$ represents the average amount you get. From this point of view, one can see that this average is $1$ more than $E(X)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if you have a general experiment with random variable $X$ it may be of interest to get the expected value of a certain function $f(X)$, for example if you get one credit more than you toss heads in a game and the number of heads is your random Variable $X$, then the amount of credit gained is given by $f(X) = X+1$. Now the expected amount of credits gained is
$$E[f] = \sum_{x\in\Omega} f(x) P(X=x) = \sum_{x\in\Omega} xP(X=x) + P(X=x) = 1+ \sum_{x\in\Omega} xP(X=x) = 1+E[X]$$
For a more complex thing, you could draw a square of side length $X$ and want to know the expected area enclosed by your square ($f(X) = X^2$) - the direct computations of the expected gain seem more difficult, but essentially they are
$$E[f] = E[X^2] = \sum_{x\in\Omega} x^2 P(X=x)$$

Comment: What is $E[X^2]$ 'saying'? If you were to put it into a sentence how would it read?

Comment: The expected value of the result squared? Or kept simple the expected number of coins if you get $X^2$ coins for $X$ heads. // Or if $E[X]=0$, $E[X^2]$ is the _[Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance)_ of the random variable.

Comment: @sonicboom: Suppose you're drawing random squares on paper, and choosing the side length randomly: you choose the side length as the random variable $X$, say. Then $E[X^2]$ denotes the expected area of the square you draw.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Nice example, I'll substitute my original (somewhat constructed) example for this if I may.

Answer (score 0):

The average of a constant is a constant. Also,
note that $\sum_x P(X = x) = 1$.